# How do I exclude outliers from an aggregate query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a report comparing total time and volume across units.  Here a simplification of the query I'm using at the moment:

```
SELECT  m.Unit,
        COUNT(*) AS Count,
        SUM(m.TimeInMinutes) AS TotalTime
FROM    main_table m
WHERE   m.unit <> ''
        AND m.TimeInMinutes > 0
GROUP BY m.Unit
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 15
```

However, I have been told that I need to exclude cases where the row's time is in the highest or lowest 5% to try and get rid of a few wacky outliers.  (As in, remove the rows before the aggregates are applied.)

How do I do that?

Comment: Here is interesting take on outlier removal - https://gavindraper.com/2018/04/30/SQL-Server-Remving-Outliers-With-Math/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can exclude the top and bottom x percentiles with NTILE

```
SELECT m.Unit,
        COUNT(*) AS Count,
        SUM(m.TimeInMinutes) AS TotalTime
FROM    
        (SELECT
             m.Unit,
             NTILE(20) OVER (ORDER BY m.TimeInMinutes) AS Buckets
         FROM
             main_table m
         WHERE
             m.unit <> '' AND m.TimeInMinutes > 0
        ) m
WHERE   
      Buckets BETWEEN 2 AND 19
GROUP BY m.Unit
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 15
```

Edit: this [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/computing-the-trimmed-mean-in-sql) has several techniques too

Comment: For 5%, should probably be `NTILE(20)` and `between 2 and 19`?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to exclude the outliers with a `not in` clause:

```
where  m.ID not in 
       (
       select  top 5 percent ID
       from    main_table 
       order by 
               TimeInMinutes desc
       )
```

And another `not in` clause for the bottom five percent.

Comment: This was my original approach, but the problem is to omit the top/bottom 5% of values, rather than records, so this wouldn't really work for that case.  I hadn't heard of @gbn's suggestion of `NTILE` before, but now I've got some reading to do.  =)

Comment: @Kyle Humfeld: Omitting the top 5% values has pretty bad edge cases for say `(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,99)`, where it would omit all `1`'s from the result set, even though `1` is clearly not an outlier

Comment: I agree completely.  However, that was my read of the original problem statement.  Do you think I misread it?  Sounds to me like a 'requirement under construction' at this point.  =)

Comment: this answer removes the top 5%, not the top 5 rows! depending on the way tsql rounds, 5% translates to one or none row at all in @Andomar s sample. doing the bottom 5% as well and if it translates to one row removed, the result would be `(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)` which looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

NTile is quite inexact. If you run NTile against the sample view below, you will see that it catches some indeterminate number of rows instead of 90% from the center.  The suggestion to use TOP 95%, then reverse TOP 90% is almost correct except that 90% x 95% gives you only 85.5% of the original dataset.  So you would have to do

```
select top 94.7368 percent *
from (
select top 95 percent *
    from 
    order by .. ASC
) X
order by .. DESC
```

First create a view to match your table column names

```
create view main_table
as
select type unit, number as timeinminutes from master..spt_values
```

Try this instead

```
select Unit, COUNT(*), SUM(TimeInMinutes)
FROM
(
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TimeInMinutes) rn,
        COUNT(*) over () countRows
    from main_table
) N -- Numbered
where rn between countRows * 0.05 and countRows * 0.95
group by Unit, N.countRows * 0.05, N.countRows * 0.95
having count(*) > 20
```

The HAVING clause is applied to the remaining set after removing outliers.
For a dataset of 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,6,19, the use of ROW_NUMBER allows you to correctly remove just one instance of the 1's.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most robust way is to sort the list into order and then exclude the top and bottom extremes. For a hundred values, you would sort ascending and take the first 95 PERCENT, then sort descending and take the first 90 PERCENT.